# onEdit event applicable to only one sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm pretty new to coding. I can get this script to work across all sheets in the document however can't get it to work on just 1 of the sheets. I have looked at similar questions and answers but can't get them to apply to this script :(

I have tried to add in if(sheet.getName() == "Delivery Tracking") but then the script won't work at all.

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var ss = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if(r.getColumn() == 9){ //To check if update cell in Column I, 1 means first column.
      ss.getRange('P'+r.getRow()).setValue(new Date()); //Set column P1 value to current date.
    }else{
      ss.getRange('P'+r.getRow()).setValue('');
    }
  }
```

Comment: "Can't get it to work" means what?

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because is nowhere defined. See if this works:

```
function onEdit(event) {
var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
if(sheet.getName() !== 'Delivery Tracking' || event.range.columnStart   
!== 9) return;
event.range.offset(0, 7).setValue(event.value ? new Date() : '');
}
```